# Can't make app: ... attributes to work in xml file

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm looking for an optimal way to resize wrapping text in a TextView so that it will fit within Width.

I am referring to this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds):
Here is official  [Android Dev page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

The problem I have app:attributes does not work even though i added implementation in gradle file. Error: "Namespace 'app' is not bound"

Here are is XML code fragment

```
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50sp"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

And here is my gradle file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ed Rantsan. Please, instead of adding a external links consider adding it in text format. It will make it easier for people to help you. For more information, please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @IgorEscodro I have deleted images and replaced them with text. Thanks for a great tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in the Parent Layout. Then you can use the `app:attributes`. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52772600/10182897) and first comment on the answer and Gradle file error shows clearly your using androidx and trying to import android version 28 library

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was referring to this comment + answer but didn't know about this part `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`